# Cannot access .js files from TIdHTTPCommandGet procedure OnCommandGet

Tags: javascript, delphi, indy, http-get

I'm making a VCL Forms Application with a TIdHTTPServer on the main form and a CommandGet of the IdHTTPServer procedure:

```
procedure TForm6.IdHTTPServerPaymentsCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
      ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  path: string;
  content: TFileStream;
begin
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
  path := GetCurrentDir.Remove(GetCurrentDir.Length - 11) + 'index.html'; // Length('Win32\Debug') = 11

  if pos('profile&userName=', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
  begin
    content := TFileStream.Create(path, fmOpenReadWrite);

    try
      AResponseInfo.ContentStream := content;
    finally
      content.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

index.html contains:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
  </head>
<body onload="sampleAlert()"><!-- sample function from script.js -->
<!-- Page content -->
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I open index.html file in browser (without starting the application) the page works fine but when I start the VCL application I have no access to script.js (when test with IE9: 'The value of the property 'sampleAlert' is null or undefined, not a Function object'). Any idea how can to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code always returns the index.html file, independent of what document the client requests. So if the client received the index.html and tries to render it, the client will detect that there is a reference to a resource scripts/script.js, and send a HTTP GET request for it to your server. But the server ignores the name of the requested resource (which is given in the RequestInfo parameter), reads the index.html file again and returns its content instead of the JavaScript file. The client expected a valid JavaScript document, and receives a HTML document instead.

To fix it, check the `ARequestInfo.Document` property, and return the content of the requested resource.

Comment: I would also suggest using `AResponseInfo.ContentStream` for physical files, just assign a `TFileStream` to it.  Don't use `TFile.ReadAllText()` to read the file into memory just to assign the `AResponseInfo.ContentText`. That is overkill.

Comment: Remy, mjn thank you for the useful advices. I have one more problem: using `ARequestInfo.Document` I cannot access .css files

Comment: @mitko.berbatov please give more details: where exactly is the difference between serving .js and .css files?

Comment: @mjn .css file is located in 'styles/style.css'; in index.html head tag I add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">; In IE9 I get: 'This stylesheet cannot be viewed because its source is in different domain than the page'

Comment: @mitko.berbatov I suggest to create a new Stackoverflow question, and include a small HTML example which which demonstrates this problem, as a reproducible test case. The error message alone does not provide enough information.

Comment: @mjn there is one more problem: when I try to access index.html (the URL is 'http://[host_ip]/?profile&userName=testUser') from other computer in chrome I get: 'Not allowed to load local resource: file://scripts/script1.js%EF%BF%BDtes'. Why this happens and how can I solve this problem

Comment: @mitko.berbatov better place this in a new question together with the page HTML code